# What are the advantages of initializing a view-controller from Main.storyboard using storyboard-ID?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-storyboard

I have seen many examples where a *view-controller* is initialized using its *storyboard-ID* in `Main.storyboard`:

```
UIPageViewController *myPageViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewControllerID"];
```

Are there any particular advantages of doing it like this instead of just doing the old ***alloc-init***?

Comment: Yes this is way to initialising the controller with `xib designed in storyboard`. You can't load the xib designed in storyboard by any other way.

Comment: But I don't want that view-controller in my `Main.storyboard` at all, I want to initialize it from the code.

Comment: You are initialising it through code only, if you want to do it the old way, create your xib separately not in storyboard.

Comment: Why would someone create a view-controller in storyboard or a separate xib and then instantiate it in the code, when the same thing could be achieved with alloc-init?

Comment: Alloc init doesn't unarchive any of the views, so the storyboard adds all of the outlet collections (same for NIB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose to use a storyboard then you either request the initial view controller (or allow the system to do it), request the view controller by identifier or trigger a segue. The advantage of requesting by identifier is that you can do whatever you want with the controller. Segues are much more powerful than they used to be and basically everything can now be done directly, but there could be some conditional logic you'd rather run (which could trigger a number of segues...).

You don't need to use a storyboard though. If you want you can create everything in code or you can continue to use NIB files. Storyboards help when you're using auto-layout and want to take advantage of the layout guides. 99% of the time using a storyboard will save you time over using just code and perhaps 50% of the time over using a NIB.